# Problem using HSQLDB Transfer Tool with MySQL

Tags: mysql, data-migration, hsqldb

I am trying to use the HSQLDB transfer tool to migrate a Database from MySQL. The tool is able to get the tables from the source MySQL database, however when I "start the transfer" I get the error,as follows and tables are not created in the target HSQLDB database.

```
org.hsqldb.util.DataAccessPointException: Unexpected token: PRIMARY in statement
 [CREATE TABLE INST(INST_ID BIGINT NOT NULL ,INST_NAME VARCHAR NOT NULL ,INST_CO
DE VARCHAR NOT NULL ,PARENT BIGINT,OPEN_TIME TIMESTAMP,CLOSE_TIME TIMESTAMP,INST
_STATUS VARCHAR NOT NULL ,SCD_LICENSE CHAR(1) NOT NULL ,ADDRESS_LINE1 VARCHAR,AD
DRESS_LINE2 VARCHAR,CITY_ID BIGINT NOT NULL ,CASH_LIMIT BIGINT,DESCRIPTION VARCH
AR,INST_TYPE VARCHAR NOT NULL ,LAST_UPDATED_BY BIGINT NOT NULL ,LAST_UPDATED_DAT
E TIMESTAMP NOT NULL , CONSTRAINT PRIMARY]
```

Any idea how I could overcome this?

My main intention is to convert MySQL SQL into HSQLDB equivalenst, I guess there uses to be a tool to do this before MySQL workbench.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says that the Transfer Tool has not been developed for several years. I think you need to create a tool by your self, which translates a MYSQL Object DDL (Create Table, Create Procedure, etc) to a HSQL Object DDL (Which is basically SQL standards 92, 1999, 2003 and 2008).
I'm currently searching for one my self.

If you find one, please update this post?